# Process of Fetching the mails of Gmail by Python (Through IMAP)

Tags: python-2.7, gmail

I have fetched the mails of Gmail through IMAP. but the output gives only the title of mails. now as a one step ahead i want to fetch the whole details of a mails.

The code through which i fetched the title of mail is:

for num in data[0].split():

```
    rv, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    if rv != 'OK':
        print ("ERROR getting message", num)
        return

    msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
    decode = email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]
    subject = unicode(decode[0])
    print ('Message %s: %s' % (num, subject))
    print ('Raw Date:', msg['Date'])

    # Now convert to local date-time
    date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(msg['Date'])
    if date_tuple:
        local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
        print ("Local Date:")
        local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Can anybody guide me?